# Function .animate in percentage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have this navigation to the right and left on my website trought a button, but it's not working when I try to use percentage, it only accepts pixels in it.

HTML:

```
<span class='leftArrow' id="left" value='left'><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></span>
<span class='rightArrow' id="right" value='right'><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></span>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".wrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '100%' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Could anyone give me a light?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollLeft` accepts only pixels see:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollleft.asp

Try:

```
$(function () {

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        var wid = $(".wrapper").width();
        $(".wrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + wid  }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh, I see, is there a way to recreate the same thing but using % ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much